# Search product not working in "New order" (Woocommerce)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have imported the products from a wordpress to another wordpress.
In backend, when I search a new product inside of "New order", it doesn't load any variable product, only the simple products.
I tried to create a new variable product, and this can be loaded in search product.

I tried too to deactivate the theme and possible conflictive plugins and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, WooCommerce will sometimes leave orphaned variations in the database after deleting the parent product.

Try using this plugin: [WooCommerce Clean Orphaned Variations](https://github.com/anttiviljami/woocommerce-clean-orphaned-variations)

> But do a backup first!